# WebView.scrollTo function not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, scrollto

I'm trying to open up a pdf document using a webview and scroll to a certain page. However, the logs show that the app thinks it scrolled to a page, but is still stuck on page 1 of the document.

My current code is as follows:

```
String pdf = https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzfmteGs4MHZMTAzOGQ0ZjUtM2E5OC00YmNhLWIyMDEtZDAxYjc5OWIwYjkw/edit?hl=en#
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl(pdf);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        web.scrollTo(0,100);
        Log.d("CURRENTPAGE", String.valueOf(web.getScrollY()));
        Log.d("TOTALPAGES", String.valueOf(view.getContentHeight()));
    }
});
```

The logs say this

```
CURRENTPAGE: 100
TOTALPAGES: 796
```

Yet the page remains on page 1 of the pdf. Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` doesn't handle PDF itself. if you are opening some `URL` inside (no download-as-file-prompt) then this is probably some web application, which is handling internally PDF format, "translating" its content to `WebView`-understandable (some web lang, HTML probably)

so if this web app is introducing its content as single web page with 796px height (you named it `TOTALPAGES`, thats not true) and handling pdf-page switching internally then you can't do much in that manner

further: your loaded webpage have 796px height and probably fit whole content into your screen, so `scrollTo` method won't have anything to scroll. if your web page height got e.g. 3456 px and your screen is full HD (so web page won't fit) then you may use `scrollTo`

Comment: What would be the actual approach to do this? The google drive pdf I shared has 63 pages. How would I scroll to a page in the pdf?

Comment: personally I think this isn't possible with third-party web app reading/showing PDFs. maybe there is an API for it written in Javascript, but I doubt... `WebView` has very limited possibilities, it's not intended to make whole advanced app using only web components - and reading/printing PDF isn't a trivial feature, it needs in fact whole engine, which undestand PDF data formatting

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll look for another approach then.